# Hi RPG! A reminder from your friends at Gaming: We don't do Recommendations

Tags: discussion, migration

Like [this one.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/12416/rpg-todo-list-like-epicwin)

Please don't migrate stuff to us that we're just going to have to close. Thanks!

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Drat, I was hoping to ask about on-the-fly mapping software. Actually I came over to meta to make sure that was cool first (I know it is on TeX.SX, but not on Gaming.SX, so thought I would check. Guess I'll head over to RPG.net and ask there.

Comment: @Canageek, you can always drop by chat and ask there ... that's typically what we suggest for people who do ask rec questions. (To be honest, we're not entirely sure how well that works either, but it's all we can offer.)

Comment: Note: the link is now dead.